# new to sql -subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

Im a newbie to SQL and having some trouble.  Im getting so far in my script than stuck.
The tables are as follows ...

Table 1: student answers. Columns:

- question id
- student answer.

Table 2: questions. Columns:

- question id
- correct answer

I have to display questions that have never been answered correctly and have been asked at least once (question id=question id).

I can get questions that have been answered incorrectly (where student answer<>correct answer) but not never been answered correctly. I'm thinking if I count the number of questions and where this equals the number answered incorrectly I will get number never answered correctly. I might be over complicating it.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from questions Q
where not exists (
        select 1
        from student_answers A
        where A.question_id = Q.question_id
            and A.student_answer = Q.correct_answer
    );
```

Comment: @trix, accept the answer, please. That's how it goes here, on stackoverflow.com. By accepting one's answer, the one is awarded with so called "reputation points".